# Classes in jconsole overflowing

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jconsole

I have a multi Thread data load job that keeps blowing up.
I watch it in jconsole and it is the classes area that seems to be growing exponentially.   I found this javassist.ClassPool where I set

```
ClassPool.doPruning = true;
```

that fixes the issue.  This seems too good to be true.  Has anyone seen any side effects from setting the pruning to true?  I haven't found any so far, but I want to keep my eyes open for issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This made it through testing without any issues and has been out in a production environment for 6 months.  Works just fine with no observable issues.

Comment: I was expecting more input on this one.  It must be pretty rare.